# NotMapped property is not supported in Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have added RunCount property in class and called in function as below.

```
 public class ItemsDataObject
 {
        [Key]
        [Column("ID")]
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
        [NotMapped]
        public int RunCount { get; set; }
 }

public static List<ItemsDataObject> GetAllItemsWithPaging(int startingPageIndex, int pageSize, string orderColumn, string orderDir)
    {
         using (var ctx = new OracleDbContext())
         {
              List<ItemsDataObject> list = new List<ItemsDataObject>();
    
              var v = (from a in ctx.Items select a);
              v = v.OrderBy(orderColumn + " " + orderDir);
              list = v.Skip(startingPageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    
              return list;
         }
    }
```

There are large data in list so i need to firstly sort items and get 10 rows(pagesize) and then .ToList().

But i am getting System.NotSupportedException error. How can i fix the issue?

> The specified type member 'RunCount' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: What is `v.OrderBy(string)`? that's not a built-in query function.

Comment: Make sure RunCount didn't sneak its way into the `orderColumn` value. One catch to trying to abstract EF with methods and parameters is that those parameters still have to conform to EF rules.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 var v = from a in ctx.Items
    orderby a.orderColumn ,a.orderDir;
  list = v.Skip(startingPageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```